# How to convert images from TIFF to JPG preserving the comments and tags

Tags: macos

I am using preview (that comes with OS X El Capitan) feature to convert a file form TIFF format into JPG for example. I expected the export process will include the original comments, but it doesn't happen (it applies also for the tag fields).

[image: Selecting the file from Preview for exporting it into JPG]

The generated JPG file has no comment

[image: Comparation of TIFF and JPG files, there is no comment on JPG file]

The compression and change image format work, but the META INFO such as comment or tags are not exported.

Any suggestion or workaround about how to include that information. I need to convert about 500 images so manually copy/paste doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have `homebrew` installed and do you mind running a few small commands in the Terminal? If that would be ok, you can use **ImageMagick** and I can assist you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I already installed `homebrew` and then `ImageMagick`, I guess I did it correctly. Let me know how to go from here. I have a root directory with several sub-folders with TIF files. I would like to replicate the root directory at different location with JPG files instead including all possible meta tags from the original file, such as comments, tags, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted this problem also in Apple Community, here is the [solution](https://discussions.apple.com/message/31266225?ac_cid=op123456) proposed by VikingOSX. It is a big piece of code, so better download it from [here](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D309535_06714578_079459) or directly from the Apple Community Link mentioned.  Here is a description about the solution as described in the original post:

- Prompts for a source folder, and a destination folder.
- Duplicates folder hierarchy from source to destination folder.
  Selects all TIFF images in the folder hierarchy and converts them to JPEG.
  For sub-folders and their files, transfers the original Finder comments, color tags and tag name(s) to the destination hierarchy.
- The compression level for the JPG file is `high`, it can be modified for: `medium` or `low` in the line: `save this_img as JPEG in outfile_name with compression level medium with icon`

**Limitation**: Source folder can only contain one-level of sub-folders. Ignoring this will result in unplanned results.

**Additional Comments**

- Uses a with timeout clause to allow for large number of files. AppleScript does not yet support Finder tag names, so this script uses `AppleScript/Objective-C` to get and set those tag name(s). Due to this extension, the script now requires AppleScript 2.4 and must be run on `OS 10.10` or later.
- Due to the `AppleScript/Objective-C` code, the script cannot be run interactively as a script/script bundle without using the `control+command+R` keyboard shortcut. A test is made when the script starts, and will warn appropriately. It is best to save the script as an application to avoid this keyboard shortcut altogether.

**Usage**

Save the [script](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D309535_06714578_079459) and then copy and paste the file contains into the Script Editor (you can find the application in the folder: Utilities under the name: Script Editor), compile and save the file with the format: Application, then double click on it to run the script application.

I have tested the script under with Mac Air 2010, with OS El Capitan, for a folder with 884 TIFF files with 2.25GB size and it takes about 18 minutes to convert them into JPG files with medium compression level. The generated files will contain the tags and comments from the original equivalent TIFF file.

**Disclaimer**

Comment and tags generated in one platform for example Windows or mac OS are not visualized in the other platform. Tags created in Windows are treated in mac OS as keywords (`Comand+i` for visualizing them), but comments generated in Windows are not visualized in mac OS. This is general incompatibility problem that apply for photos in any format (for example TIFF or JPG).

**EDIT** (updated solution for solving cross-platform problem with comments)

Taking the idea from @MarkSetchell, I adapted the original script to at least solve the cross-platform problem from macOS to Windows, i.e. a comment from macOS can be seen in Windows platform. The idea is to use EXIF metadata. Then the Applescript will invoke the shell script for invoking the `exiftool`:

```
set uxFilepath to POSIX path of NewIMG 
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool  -overwrite_original -EXIF:UserComment=\"" & cmtstr & "\" " & uxFilepath
```

Windows processes the UserComment metadata from EXIF as a regular file comment. Now same comment on the TIF file will be on the JPG and also because such comments were copied (copy-paste) into an EXIF metadata the same information will be visualized under Windows. The same idea can be used for other file properties, in case Windows/Mac read it.

The EXIF metadata in macOS can be visualized from command line as suggest @MarkSetchell, but also from Finder: `Command+o` (to launch preview app), then `Command+i` (to launch the inspector). Then click on tap: "More Info", then the tab EXIF.

[image: How visualize EXIF metadata from Finder]

For the opposite process will require an script that does the opposite, i.e., copy EXIF comment using `exiftool`, into macOS comment. I have verified that in such case the Windows comment will appear under the label: `XPComment`. The script uses: `UserComment`, but it works using `XPComment` as label in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

In the light of your comments, I think the best way forward is to try and identify *how/where* the comments are stored for each platform (Windows vs macOS) and then to decide which method you want to use going forward.

macOS Finder/Spotlight comments will not be legible on Windows, so if you want Windows compatibility, you need to standardise on JPEG or EXIF comments.

I recommend using `exiftool` which you can install with `homebrew`, using:

```
brew install exiftool
```

Then I suggest you try extracting the comments from your files to see how/where they are stored:

```
exiftool -a image.jpg
```

will show you all tags in `image.jpg`. Your comments may be under:

- comment - which is the JPEG comment, or
- EXIF:UserComment - which is the EXIF comment

If you find your comments in the JPEG or the EXIF section, you can extract just the comments with:

```
exiftool -comment image.jpg             # extract JPEG comment
exiftool -EXIF:UserComment image.jpg    # extract EXIF UserComment
```

Add the option `-s3` to suppress the field-names in the above to save having to parse them out.

Likewise, you can set the comments with:

```
exiftool -comment="FUNKY JPEG COMMENT" image.jpg                  # set JPEG comment
exiftool -EXIF:UserComment="FUNKY EXIF USER COMMENT" image.jpg    # set EXIF UserComment
```

You can also extract the EXIF user comments to a CSV with:

```
exiftool -EXIF:UserComment -csv *.jpg

SourceFile,UserComment
a.jpg,FUNKY EXIF:UserComment
b.jpg,b FUNKY EXIF:UserComment
```

You can also apply comments from a CSV.

You should also be able to extract macOS/Spotlight/Finder comments using the script in my main answer:

```
$HOME/macOSGetFinderComment "/Users/someone/soneFile.tif"
```

**Original Answer**

I would suggest you try the following using **ImageMagick**.

First, use the Finder, or any other tool you are familiar with, to make a copy of your photos including the entire directory structure to some new place where we cannot damage your existing photos. So, let's say you **copy** (NOT move) the entire tree of TIFs to a subdirectory called "NEW" inside your HOME directory.

Then start the Terminal and change directory to "NEW":

```
cd NEW
```

**Easy Method**

If all the TIFs are in a single directory or two, just use `mogrify`:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.tif
```

**Harder Method**

If the TIF files are in multiple directories, you will need to work a bit harder. Inside Terminal copy and paste this:

```
find NEW -name \*.tif -exec sh -c 'new="${1%.tif}.jpg"; convert "{}" "$new"' _ {} \;
```

That starts looking in the "NEW" directory for files named "*.tif". When it finds one, it starts a new shell (`sh`) passing it the filename of the TIF. It then works out the new filename by replacing a trailing "tif" with "jpg" and invokes **ImageMagick** `convert` to do the conversion.

---

As regards the Finder/Spotlight comments, here is a little script to get the Finder comment of a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# macOSGetFinderComment
# Pass an absolute path to the file!
file=$1
osascript<<EOF
    tell application "Finder" to get comment of item POSIX file "$file"
EOF
```

And here is one to set the Finder/Spotlight comment:

```
#!/bin/bash
# macOSSetFinderComment
# Pass an absolute path to the file!
file=$1
comm=$2
osascript<<EOF
    tell application "Finder" to set comment of item POSIX file "$file" to "$comm"
EOF
```

So, I would save those 2 scripts in your HOME directory and then make them executable with:

```
cd
chmod +x macOS*FinderComment
```

Then save this file in your HOME directory under $HOME/CopyComments:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for f in $(pwd)/*.tif; do
    comment=$($HOME/macOSGetFinderComment "$f")
    new="${f%.tif}.jpg"
    echo Setting comment of $new to $comment
    $HOME/macOSSetFinderComment "$new" "$comment"
done
```

and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/CopyComments
```

and run it with:

```
cd NEW
$HOME/CopyComments
```

Comment: I see now from your added images that you are talking about `Finder/Spotlight` comments and maybe (?) OSX tags, rather than comments in images and tags in a Tagged Image File (TIF). So, I will look at copying the Finder comments across to the JPGs when I have a minute or ten...

Comment: apparently the version of ImageMagick 7.0.4-3 Q16 x86_64 2017-01-1 I have installed (installed with: `brew install imagemagick`) does not support the conversion from tif->jpg, the opposite works. After `convert from.tif to.jpg` I get the following error: `convert: no decode delegate for this image format 'TIFF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508`. Invoking: `identify from.tif` I get the same error.

Comment: Try `brew install libtiff`, then `brew rm imagemagick` and `brew install imagemagick`

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to handle transferring the comments from the TIF files to the JPG files now.

Comment: I followed the steps you mentioned. I saved all files without extension. When I execute the last command `$HOME/CopyComments`, but I get the command prompt and no echo line. I think it has to be with the bash shell execution, but I don't know how.

Comment: Ok, did ImageMagick create all the JPGs from your TIFs? Please put one TIF which contains a comment in your HOME directory calling it `test.tif`, and in Terminal, run `$HOME/macOSGetFinderComment "$HOME/test.tif"` and see if it can extract the comment.

Comment: I executed: `bash macOSGetFinderComment file1.tif` and I got: 
`37:44: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)`. I have also verified that in CopyComments, it doesn't go inside the for block, the statement: `$(pwd)/*.tif` return nothing.

Comment: You need to run the command exactly as I said please - with the $HOME part.

Comment: I run exactly the same: `$HOME/macOSGetFinderComment "$HOME/test.tif"` with identical result: 
`37:44: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)` from `$HOME` location.

Comment: Please run `ls -l $HOME | pbcopy` and click `edit` under your original question and paste in the results.

Comment: That's odd, everything looks ok. Did you do `cd NEW` before running `$HOME/CopyComments`?

Comment: yes...I am running `$HOME/CopyComments` from `NEW` folder. Thanks any way. I found a solution in another forum (I will post it here). That solves the problem. It copy the comments and tags for the JGP files, but I can see them only under macOS, when It try to see the generated image in a PC I cannot see such properties, but this is a general problem, because from the original TIFF file sometimes I have the same problem too.

Comment: I can show you how to get the comments from the OSX Spotlight/Finder comments into the embedded JPEG comment which PC's can read if that is what you want...

Comment: That would be great.! I didn't know this cross-platform problem when I started to work with my photos (I have now 884 photos!), and some comments where created in Windows and others in mac OS, and I am not able to identify which comments where created on which platform. It would be great to unify all the information, copying the existing comment/tags into the property that is used by the other platform, something like: `copyWindowsComments2mac` and `copyMacCommments2Windows` or even a comment extractor into a `*.csv`. file and update comment process with and input file. Any help would great.

Comment: For `exiftool` solution, in my case for Windows picture the comments are stored in property: `XP Comment` for a tif file. It can be obtained via: `exiftool -EXIF:XPComment AV002.tif` for example. That should work great!, but now I realized that if from preview app I crop the photo and save it, all XP information disappeared. I have croped many of them already, so I am afraid I missed this information. Probably the only solution will be to go back to the original windows files and to repeat all the crop process after getting the comment information using your suggestion.

Comment: I have also noticed that for a photo already saved in macOS, the comment information you see with: `Comand+i`, is not stored in the file properties that can be extracted using: `exiftool -a image.jpg`. Therefore the solution is great for extracting the windows comment, but then we need something else for saving windows comment in a way it can be visualized with the Get Info action on the file.